# How to change attribute of a React Element

Tags: reactjs

I've created a render method which adds a number of dynamically created 'InfoWindow' elements to a Class based object.

Each InfoWindow element has a unique ID and key.

I also have a number of 'Marker' elements with corresponding ids and keys.

Currently all Infowindows have a prop of 'visible={false}'

When I click a Marker a function is called which outputs the Marker ID.

I'd like to find the InfoWindow with the relevant ID and set visibility = {true}

Is there a way to find the relevant InfoWindow element using its key or ID, and then call setAttribute (or equivalent)?

I've tried searching the DOM for the ID but Google Maps doesn't render that way, so I'm thinking there must be a more React-y way to do this?

```
let visibilityFunction = () => {
  this.changeVisibility(01);
};

changeVisibility = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    //this currently outputs the ID (01)
}


render() {

    return( 
        <Parent>
            <InfoWindow
                visible={false} 
                key={01-iw} 
                id={01-iw}
             />
            <Marker
                key={01} 
                id={01}
                onClick={visibilityFunction}
             />
        </Parent>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is where you would use `state`, set a visibility flag on state key'd by `id`, and then use on the relevant element. I'd recommend [**reading the docs on state**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), this is a  well documented use case. It's best to know how to use the framework first so you dont go searching down the wrong path :). Furthermore, you aren't using this correctly, you have a render method but it doesn't look like you are using a class considering `visibilityFunction` isn't tied to the class?

Answer (score 3):

Like I was saying in the comments. Use state here to update the visibility.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { visibleWindows: {}, currentWindows: [1] };

  changeVisibility = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      visibleWindows: {
        ...prevState.visibleWindows,
        [id]: !prevState.visibleWindows[id]
      }
    }));
  };
  render() {
    const { currentWindows, visibleWindows } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {currentWindows.map(win => (
          <ChildWindow key={win} id={win} isVisible={!!visibleWindows[win]} onChange={this.changeVisibility} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildWindow extends React.Component {
  changeVisibility = () => {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.id)
  }
  render() {
    <React.Fragment>
      <InfoWindow
        visible={this.props.isVisible}
        key={`${win}-iw`}
        id={`${win}-iw`}
      />
      <Marker
        key={win}
        id={win}
        onClick={this.changeVisibility}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  }
}
```

### [Here's a rudimetary example for you to poke around with :)](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-4iklq)

Comment: `this.changeVisibility.bind` isn't necessary since you're already using an arrow function as the value of `changeVisibility` in the class definition. Just `() => this.changeVisibility(win)` would be clearer I think.

Comment: How? Both create a new function each render.

Comment: let me look up the performance test. Javascript treats `.bind` in a more performant way than an inline lambda. Really I should just make a child component that doesn't need a new function for each render :)

Comment: define "way less" :-)

Comment: @EmileBergeron This isn't what I remember reading, but its about the same in terms of results. https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/9f3hhf/bound_function_vs_arrow_function_performance/

Comment: Those passive-aggressive emoticons are getting out of hand :-)

Comment: First, the link compares another thing, which is a class definition, and here, we're talking inline expressions. And anyway, you're using an arrow function in your class definition, which is "slower" according to your link in that specific case.

Comment: The other thing is, even in the link, comments mention that it depends on the platform and the performance results are unreliable.

Comment: Finally, performance is the least of our concerns here, and readability should be our main goal.

Comment: And it doesn't matter that much in the end, since it's just `.bind` vs `=>`. My point was that a lot of React users misuse (or overuse) `.bind` when unnecessary and I thought that we could avoid such confusion by avoiding `.bind` altogether.

Comment: Like I was saying it wasn't the article I read but it shows a slower performance when using bind. The class syntax is used on both so that would be 0'd out. I'm using an arrow sure, but that's on the class as a method... So it's created once not each render cycle? Completely different point. I wasn't trying to be passive aggressive sorry if that's how the smiley was taken :(

Comment: In your _initial_ code, an arrow function _was_ created once in the class, and `.bind` created a new one each render cycle.

Comment: Sure, I agree an arrow is more readable, I always try to write performant code and or keep it in mind because I have had performance issues before. 60fps 3D react applications for instance. So I just default to writing something with performance in mind.

Comment: I dislike when people say we shouldn't be worried about performance, we should always keep that in mind and try to write good clean performant code. Readability is definitely a high point on my radar too, hence the refactor to a child component.

Comment: And yes, initially I was using .bind each render cycle. My only point is that it's approx 1.5x to 2x more performant than an arrow in the render method. What's the issue?

Comment: Just for the sake of the conversation, here's my opinion: We shouldn't worry about performance until it gets necessary. Doesn't mean we should write dumb code though. Adding new features and minimizing maintainability overhead is just way more important most of the time. While a child component does avoid redefining a function each render cycle, it's overkill in our situation here and we could argue that it's also detrimental to the overall readability because of the additional complexity.